# Problem to convert curl to php, I can't solve it

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm having problems converting curl to php, I need to access data in json and filter this data. I was able to access the data without the filter but I can't access it when I add the filter.

The code below is functional and brings all the data in json...

`

```
<?php
$apikey = 'myapikey';
$outputType = 'json';
$url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/contasreceber/' . $outputType;
$retorno = executeGetOrder($url, $apikey);
echo $retorno;
function executeGetOrder($url, $apikey){
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '&apikey=' . $apikey);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $response;
    
}
?>
```

`

This was the code I tried to run to apply the filters as the developer described.

As stated in the developer's api manual https://ajuda.bling.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/360047064873-GET-contasreceber

I would be very grateful if someone could help me my knowledge is limited and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

`

```
<?php
$apikey = 'myapikey';
$outputType = 'json';
$url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/contasreceber/' . $outputType;
$retorno = executeGetOrder($url, $apikey);
echo $retorno;
function executeGetOrder($url, $apikey){
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '&apikey=' . $apikey);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'filters=dataEmissao[01/01/2022 TO 05/02/2022]; situacao[Aberto]');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $response;
    
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you're sending "POSTFIELDS", but using the "GET" request method.

Comment: @droopsnoot Sorry for the naivety, I'm very limited and have little knowledge... How should I rewrite this code. Sorry if the translation wasn't good.

Comment: If it is just a get request, file_get_contents( $url . '&apikey=' . $apikey ); should get what your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative when making a get request.

```
<?php
$apikey = 'my api key';
$outputType = 'json';
$filters ="cnpj[21.416.959/0001-82]";
$url = 'https://bling.com.br/Api/v2/contasreceber/' . $outputType;
$retorno = executeGetOrder($url, $apikey, $filters); 
echo $retorno;

function executeGetOrder($url, $apikey, $filters){ 
   return file_get_contents( $url.'&apikey=' . $apikey . '&filters=' . $filters`);        
}
?>
```

Comment: Very good, it cleaned the code a lot. My biggest problem is filtering this data to restrict the return.

Comment: Thank you very much @NickMaroulis, you solved my problem, I adjusted this way and managed to filter the data the way I expected, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I look on your documentation, `date` does not exist.

You can only have as filters :

- dataEmissao * ;
- dataVencimento * ;
- situacao ;
- cnpj ;
- dataPagamento *;

The ones I put `*` are the filters with date inputs so you need, depending of your wanted :

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'filters=dataEmissao[01/01/2022 TO 05/02/2022]; situacao[open]');
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to translate the string into English to make it easier to understand and ended up confusing it... I ran it with the correct filter, but I still don't get any data returned or even any of the errors in the developer's manual.

Comment: I made the API available for testing, remembering that the code without a filter is bringing the data but with the parameters to carry out the filter it does not return information.